# customize js2-mode switch indentation

Tags: indentation, javascript

This is pretty simple but it's thwarting me:

this is how a switch statement indents in js2-mode

```js
  switch(letterGrade){
  case "A+":
    value = 100  ; break;
  case "A":
    value = 97 ; break;
```

this is how I want it to indent:

```js
  switch(letterGrade){
    case "A+":
      value = 100  ; break;
    case "A":
      value = 97 ; break;
```

How can I make that happen? And, as a side question, why doesn't js2-mode use the same indenting stuff as other C-like languages?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`js2-mode` derives from `js-mode`. So you need set up `js-mode` in this case.

`(setq js-switch-indent-offset 2)` is enough.

Comment: Perfect, thank you!

Comment: Knowing that js2 inherits js-mode properties is even more useful.